# Use Newton's method to find all solutions of $5\cos(x) = x + 1$ correct to six decimal places.

Tags: calculus, newton-raphson

Use Newton's method to find all solutions of the equation correct to six decimal places. (Enter your answers as a comma-separated list.)

$5\cos(x) = x + 1$

I got $1.130597$ as an answer but apparently I am suppose to have 3 different answers. Also how do I find the initial approximation? Thank you

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @Max thank you for cleaning up my post

Comment: Use inspection for a few values $x=-k \pi$

Comment: there are three solutions

Answer (score 2):

Let
$$
f(x)=5\cos(x)-x-1
$$
Then $f(x)=0$ can be solved using the recursion
$$
\begin{align}
x_{n+1}
&=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}\\
&=x_n-\frac{5\cos(x_n)-x_n-1}{-5\sin(x_n)-1}\\
&=\frac{5x_n\sin(x_n)+5\cos(x_n)-1}{5\sin(x_n)+1}
\end{align}
$$
where $x_1$ is near some root of $f$.

Plotting $f(x)$,

[image]

we see that there are roots near $-4,-2,+1$. Apply the recursion to $x_1\in\{-4,-2,+1\}$.

Answer (score 0):

For Newton use e.g. the start values $1$, $-2$ and $-4$ because the start values have to be *near by* the solution. (It's not difficult to create your list, you can easily create it yourself.)

---

*Note* without Newton, only a recursion:

It's $\cos 2x=2\cos^2 x-1$.

To avoid the cyclic property of cosine, the variable of cosine should be less than $\pi/2$ . For the first solution with start value $1$ you can use $5\cos x -x-1$ but for the second solution with start value $-2$ you should use e.g.  $10\cos^2(\frac{x}{2})-x-6$ and for the third solution with the start value $-4$ it's senseful to use e.g. $40\cos^2(\frac{x}{4})-40\cos(\frac{x}{4})-x+4$ .